# Placing Jquery no Conflict in Rails 3.1.3 Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My application is using both prototype and jquery and all files are being getting load by application.js file but i need to add jquery.noconflict(), how can i handle that and where to add this noconflict line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By thinking some time got its solution. Beside of using noconflict of jquery i was also require to load files with particular order so they dont get conflict.

For this i overwrite application.js file and list down all required js files in required order and one of the js was having jquery.noconflict line to make jquery and protype both compatible.

like

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

//= require noconflict
//= require prototype
//= require compose
//= require s3_upload
```

and remove the last line require_tree so assets compiler does not add files by its own.

Thanks every one who look in to this question.